# Making array from user input (Seperated by linebreaks) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, user-input

I am trying to take user input in form of a lot of strings. I want to store them in an array, and the input should be seperated by line breaks.

It should be very much like this: https://www.random.org/lists/

I can not grasp where to being - can someone help? I am using JavaScript but any solutions using JS or jQuery would be great!

I have posted my JS. I want the var people from user input, instead of having to populate the array myself.

Thanks,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".btn").on('click', function() {
     var people = ["Markus Eriksson", "Leticia Hoshino", "Yemi Afolabi", "Eskil Fogelström", "Josefina Liedberg", "David Bjørn Bograd", "Tilda Dahlgren", "Damien Vignol", "Sofie Cousu", "Carolina Lindelöw", "Bilal Khan", "Louise Brandrup-Wognsen", "Emilia Lehto", "Albin Hagström",
       "Victor Borg", "Anna Stella Lo-Ré", "Loucmane", "Angelica Ruth", "Victoria VL", "Johan Hellström", "Micke Skoglund", "Anna Unger", "Isaac Sennerholt", "Cyndie Léa Vintilescu", "Mahle Rakela Robin", "Louise Ek", "Ibrahim Bajwa", "Abodi Ismail",
       "Alex Ashman", "Elin Grass Casalini", "Amanda Schultz", "Abenezer Abebe", "Julia Hoff", "Enny Hellsén", "Michel George", "Abdullahi Hussein", "Teodor Meurling", "Andrea Sami Mogren", "Thea Arpine Gasparyan", "Jakob Eberson"
     ];
     var groupSize = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
     var groups = [];

     $(".group").remove();

     // Randomizing function
     Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
       var input = this;

       for (var i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

         var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
         var itemAtIndex = input[randomIndex];

         input[randomIndex] = input[i];
         input[i] = itemAtIndex;
       }
       return input;
     };

     people.shuffle();

     // Split people into chunks and push new arrays into var groups
     while (people.length > 0) {

       chunks = people.splice(0, groupSize);
       var chunksSpace = chunks.join(', ');

       groups.push(chunksSpace);
     }

     // Append the groups into the DOM
     $(document).ready(function() {
       for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
         $('.all-groups').append("<div class='group'><p><span class='groupheader'>Group " + (i + 1) + "</span></br> " + groups[i] + "</p></div>");
       }
     });
   });
 });
```

Comment: Show us what code you've wrote so far.

Comment: @KhorshedAlam I have now added my JS code I use to randomize the array. What I want from user input is the var people.

Comment: JS document.getElementById("element_id").value.split("\n"); or JQuery $("#element_id").val().split("\n");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pure Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("element_id").value.split("\n");
```

**OR JQuery** `$("#element_id").val().split("\n");`

For your example give your input `id='people'` and should work, also avoid extra line breaks by `.replace(/\n+/g,"\n")`.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {    
     // Randomizing function
     Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
       var input = this;

       for (var i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

         var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
         var itemAtIndex = input[randomIndex];

         input[randomIndex] = input[i];
         input[i] = itemAtIndex;
       }
       return input;
     };

   $(".btn").on('click', function() {
     var people = $("#people").val().replace(/\n+/g,"\n").split("\n");
     var groupSize = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
     var groups = [];

     $(".group").remove();

     people.shuffle();

     // Split people into chunks and push new arrays into var groups
     while (people.length > 0) {

       chunks = people.splice(0, groupSize);
       var chunksSpace = chunks.join(', ');

       groups.push(chunksSpace);
     }

     // Append the groups into the DOM
     $(document).ready(function() {
       for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
         $('.all-groups').append("<div class='group'><p><span class='groupheader'>Group " + (i + 1) + "</span></br> " + groups[i] + "</p></div>");
       }
     });
   });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mamdouh, also for explaining and using the code in context. Made me understand what was happening, and now it is working for me!

Comment: You are welcome and i'm glad to help you any time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = $('#total-number').text();
var eachLine = text.split('\n');
  alert('Lines found: ' + eachLine.length);
  for(var i = 0, l = eachLine.length; i < l; i++) {
      alert('Line ' + (i+1) + ': ' + eachLine[i]);
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` to split a multi line string into parts:

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");

textarea.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    console.log(textarea.value.split((/[\n\r]/g)));
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Regex links:

- [`\r`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-carriage-return)
- [`\n`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-line-feed)